# I want to select each value in dropdown and it is coming dynamically to do unit testing using protractor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, karma-jasmine

This is my select tag

```
 <select id="selectPrimaryObject" class="form-control" ng-change="getPrimaryRelations()" ng-model="relation.from">
                <option id="md-option" ng-repeat="item in primaryObjectsList" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

And my protractor code is

```
 element.all(by.id('selectPrimaryObject')).each(function (values, index) {
        values.click();                    // select the <select>
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);              // wait for the renderings to take effect
        element.all(by.id('md-option')).click();   // select the first md-option
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);              // wait for the renderings to take effect
    });
```

It is selecting last item from dropdown, but I want each item to be selected one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the options *by repeater*, click every option with the help of [`each()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each):

```
var selectElement = element(by.id('selectPrimaryObject'));
selectElement.click();

var options = selectElement.all(by.repeater('item in primaryObjectsList'));
options.each(function (option) {
    option.click();
});
```

Comment: after using your code also it is working same as my previous code...i want to click on each option and i want to wait for 3 seconds for rendering the list of items on grid respect to that value..and it should be repeated till the end of options

Comment: @SYEDRASHEED you can tweak it and add the waits into the provided code where needed.